# Webpack: resolve transitive dependencies of linked modules

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, node-modules, babel-loader

I'm trying to implement a node module which should be installable on another module and be responsible to bundle it into a react app for me. (similar to [create react app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app))

A simplified proof of concept can be found [here](https://github.com/marcellomontemagno/babel-bundler-test)

`example` is an hello world module.

`example` depends from `bundler` which uses `webpack`+`babel` to bundle `example` into an app.

Currently running `npm run build` on `example` results into an error as `webpack` is not able to resolve `react` and `react-dom` which are transitive dependencies present in `bundler`

Running `npm run build` on `example` works as intended if `bundler` is installed via an npm pack instead of a local path such as

```
"devDependencies": {
  "bundler": "../bundler"
}
```

because during the installation npm lifts the transitive dependencies inside `example/node_module` (this doesn't happen when installing from a local path like I currently do)

I'm aware I could add the following config to webpack to "fix the issue":

```
resolve: {
  modules: [
    'node_modules',
    'node_modules/bundler/node_modules'
  ],
},
```

But in my opinion this is not a real solution because if `example` depends on another local module `example2` webpack would then fail to resolve transitive dependencies coming from `example2` and another `resolve.modules` entry would need to be added.

Is there a way to make this work keeping the modules separate and not nested?